# QT6 C++ Obtaining value from SQL Procedure OUT parameter

Tags: c++, sql, qt6

I'm having method in c++:

```
bool User::checkCredentials(){

    QSqlQuery query{};

    bool isValid{false};

    //validate_credentials(IN in_login VARCHAR(20), IN in_password VARCHAR(20), OUT out_is_valid BOOLEAN)
    query.prepare("CALL validate_credentials(?, ?, ?)");

    query.addBindValue(login);
    query.addBindValue(password);
    query.addBindValue(isValid, QSql::Out);

    if(query.exec()){
        isValid = query.boundValue(2).toBool();
        qInfo() << isValid;
    }

    else{
        qWarning() << "Failed to execute validate_credentials: " << query.lastError().text();
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

And a very simple procedure in SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE validate_credentials(IN in_login VARCHAR(20), IN in_password VARCHAR(20), INOUT out_is_valid BOOLEAN)
BEGIN
SET out_is_valid = TRUE;
END;
```

The problem is that the isValid always prints false even though I'm literally setting it to true.
Also won't work if argument is just OUT.

I tried to solve the problem on my own of course and I ran out of options, this c++ code that You see is literally as QT's documentation suggests. Of course, probably I made a mistake somewhere, or I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Documentation I checked: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values

Comment: I suppose you never reach the line with the `qWarning`, do you?

Comment: Yea. The question got solved on: https://forum.qt.io/topic/151518/qt6-can-t-read-the-out-parameter-from-mysql-database/5?_=1698444157862